# How to call Oracle stored procedures from R (with ROracle package)

Tags: sql-server, r, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I use ROracle package as the tool to process data in Oracle RDBMS.
So far I have done selects only and everything is Ok.

However I need to call the stored procedure that creates a table in oracle. Then make 'commit'.

I have not found a clear guidance of the way to make such an action. The description of ROracle package (from cran) contains 'dbCallProc' but it seems to be under development. Oracle R community looks to have not many comments about it.

So my question is how to run correclty the oracle stored procedure from R environment:

**Connection to Oracle:**

```
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")  
con <- dbConnect(drv, user, password, DB_name,bulk_read = rows_at_time)
```

**the Oracle stored procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure create_table(table_name IN varchar2)  
is
string_SQL varchar2(1000);

begin  
  string_SQL:='create table stored_table  
               as  
               select *
               from ' || table_name;
execute immediate (string_SQL);
commit;

end create_table;
```

Comment: can't you just run that stored procedure definition as normal SQL, then execute it using `exec your_procedure();`

Comment: @cory
Thanks for the comment. But I have experimented successfully with x <- dbSendQuery(con, paste("begin create_table(table_name=>",table_name,"); end;",sep="",collapse=""))